# Событие scroll : jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется блок `<header>` и при скролле, когда `<header>` уже не видно, нужно сделать его фиксированным, чтобы его было постоянно видно.

[Я решил это так.](https://jsfiddle.net/2fg6aj3b/)

Код JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop(),
        $bottom = $('.bottom');
    if( !$bottom.hasClass('fix') && scroll > 50 ){
        $bottom.addClass('fix');
    }else if( $bottom.hasClass('fix') && scroll <= 50) {
        $bottom.removeClass('fix');
    }
})
```

Но меня интересует следующее в этом JS-коде:

Получается, что при скроллинге будет постоянно вызываться этот обработчик?
Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы этот обработчик срабатывал только в верхней части страницы, т.е. чтобы не перегружать браузер лишними обработчиками?
Как обычно решается эта проблема?
И правильно ли я сделал обработчик?

Comment: Проблема "частого отстрела" решается использованием throttle/debounce , (например, готовый плагин для этого https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce , либо можете написать своё ) , т.е. перед каждым запуском функции в обработчике идет проверка, не запускалась ли она недавно. Если запускалась, то повторно функция не запускается.

Comment: @br3t, как делать эту проверку? т.е. запускалась ли недавно функция

Comment: Написали же [либу](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) использовать

Comment: я ведь не спрашивал , какой нужен плагин для этого. хотелось бы узнать, как это реализовать самому, в плагине может быть много лишнего

Comment: Ничего там лишнего. Что за ерунду говоришь? Это в jQuery много лишнего, но сейчаc не времена dial-ap. А в этом плагине к jQuery Только две функции. https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce/blob/master/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js

Comment: По [моей ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/674089/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-scroll-jquery#comment982381_674089) как раз и написано как реализовать

Comment: @br3t, хорошо, допустим установил я этот плагин.

Comment: но ведь если сделать задержку допустим 500ms и не обрабатывать скролл в течение этого промежутка времени, тогда как узнать, что пользователь прокрутил страницу вниз? ведь пользователь может прокрутить снова вверх назад, а обработчик будет отключен 500ms,

Comment: как правильно применить этот плагин, чтобы не вызывался постоянно вышеприведенный код?

Comment: Там 2 функции: одна запускает только первый раз ваш обработчик и пропускает остальные запуски, вторая запускает только в последний раз.

Comment: @br3t, что-то вышеприведённая ссылка не работает.  А можете показать простой пример со скроллом?

Comment: @word, вот вам пример https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/2k0Lkpvt/

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Закрепить блок меню](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/613350/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e)

Answer (score 1):

```js
let callBack = function() {
    $(this).off("scroll", callBack);
    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop(),
        $bottom = $('.bottom');
    if( !$bottom.hasClass('fix') && scroll > 50 ){
        $bottom.addClass('fix');
    }else if( $bottom.hasClass('fix') && scroll <= 50) {
        $bottom.removeClass('fix');
    }
    setTimeout(()=>$(this).scroll(callBack),30);

    console.log(scroll)
}

$(window).scroll(callBack)
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ,кстати этот код не всегда срабатывает, т.е. если допустим нужно сделать шапку фиксированной при скроле, то шапка не всегда фиксируется, особенно если скролить очень быстро

Comment: @word можно уменьшить таймер `setTimeout`. в сниппете работает как надо.